# Is there a difference between [usage] and [word-usage]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two separate tags, both with several questions each: [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage)

Are they the same thing, or is there a subtle difference between the two?

Comment: There is in somebody's mind. There isn't in everybody's.

Answer (score 2):

From their tag-wikis:

> [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) — How and why certain words are used in varying ways within various contexts.
>
> [word-usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) — This tag is for questions about correctly using a word.

There doesn't seem to be a significant difference and it would probably be useful to merge these two tags.

Comment: Why bother? The system is hopelessly confused and inconsistent as it is. To make it work, we'd have to start all over and do it right. Bandaids aren't helpful.

Comment: @JohnLawler: We should bother because there isn't a currently useful distinction between the two tags. If you have other concerns or complaints about the tagging system, feel free to start a meta thread on the subject.

Comment: Neither one means anything. `usage`, by its definition, covers every single question and answer on the site. How helpful is that?

Comment: @JohnLawler: It's not, I agree. But, IMO, having two useless tags is worse than having one useless tag. I'm not personally taking a hard look at tags right now. Once Unanswered gets near 150 or so I'll probably move into tags and start figuring out what greater things need changing/fixing. If you have any particular recommendations/issues I'd love to hear them.